# Can you find the length of a string from an array of pointers to strings?

Tags: c, arrays, string

Can you find the length of a string by doing subtraction on an array of pointers to strings?
For example if I have the code below

```
char *pStrings[4] = {
    "First string",
    "Hello",
    "Afternoon",
    "Ab"
};

int firstStrLen = pStrings[1] - pStrings[0] - 1; //Will I get the length of the first string by doing this?
```

Will `firstStrLen` be the length of the first string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. There is no guarantee that the strings will be located next to each other in the memory.

Comment: Is there a way to make the strings be allocated next to each other in memory?

Comment: Yes, define them in an array, however, this will not help you calculating the string's length.

Comment: @Rm32a You could define `char myStringData[] = "First string\0Hello\0Afternoon\0Ab"; char *pStrings[4] = {myStringData, myStringData+13, myStringData+19, myStringData+29}` or something like that. (But why would you?)

Answer (score 6):

No, this is undefined behavior.

You are allowed to subtract pointers only when they are pointing to memory from the same contiguous memory block. In your example `pStrings[1]` and `pStrings[0]` are not pointing to a contiguous block of memory, so the result of `pStrings[1] - pStrings[0]` is undefined.

> 6.5.6.9: When two pointers are subtracted, both shall point to elements of the same array object, or one past the last element of the array object; the result is the difference of the subscripts of the two array elements.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example that shows what @dasblinkenlight and @MByD were saying.

```
char*s1 = "Hello";
char *pStrings[4] = {
    "First string",
    "Hello",
    "Afternoon",
    "Ab"
};
```

In the above code, the compiler may (and probably will) point s1 and pStrings[1] to the same location, which may be nowhere near where pStrings[0] points. So even if the subtraction were legal (it is not), your method would not work.